# How to avoid rails as_json creating flood of database requests

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a model **questions** that has many **tags** through another model **question_tags**. I am trying to write an api endpoint that returns a list of questions and for each question a list of it's related tag's name and id.

I'm currently using;

```
render json: @questions.as_json(include: {
                                      tags: { only: %i[id name] }
                                    })
```

But this runs a separate db request for every question in questions is there an alternative that will result in a smaller number of database requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard N+1 queries fixes should work here, which in Rails is eager loading.

In this case you can use `include` to preload the associated `tags`:

```rb
render json: @questions.includes(:tags).as_json(
  include: {
    tags: { only: %i[id name] }
  }
)
```

You can read more about this in the dedicated rails guide section: [Eager Loading Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)